# windows batch file findstring doesn't work

Tags: batch-file, findstr

Hi I'm trying to find a string in a text file with the following batch:

```
@echo on
findstr /m "Failures: 0"  result.txt
if %errorlevel%==0 (
echo The test is good !
)else (
echo The test is fail !
)
```

where result.txt is something like

```
SGHDSAKGHADGFNA
dfjhytdjkyd
gfhjdgkgl
Failures: 1 Skip: 0
werthjrsh
```

or

```
SGHDSAKGHADGFNA
dfjhytdjkyd
gfhjdgkgl
Failures: 0 Skip: 0
werthjrsh

....
```

but in both cases the result is

```
The test is fail !
```

thanks

Mariano

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
findstr /m /c:"Failures: 0" result.txt
if not errorlevel 1 (echo "Found it!") else echo "not found!"
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternate method is this:

```
findstr /m /c:"Failures: 0" result.txt && echo Found it!
```

The command after the `&&` will only run if `findstr` finds the string.

Comment: This method may be written in a clearer way with the aid of `set "IF="` and `set "THEN=&&"` auxiliary variables this way: `%IF% findstr /m /c:"Failures: 0" result.txt %THEN% echo Found it!`

Comment: That's clever, but I think that's much more obfuscated and error-prone in a script any larger than the one OP provided.